# Symfony2 doctrine:generate:entities chmod operation not permitted

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, chmod

Recently upgraded from 2.3.1 to 2.8.7 on a dev machine.
All has been going fine until I needed to create a new table.
Managed to generate the yml fine via doctrine:mapping:convert

When I come to create the getters and setters via doctrine:generate:entities I get this:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]
Warning: chmod(): Operation not permitted
```

And nothing else. Which isn't very helpful. Is it a chmod which I need to add an @ to somewhere?
I am executing the command as www-data and the log folder files are also www-data, so I don't believe it is a debug file permission issue.

Also, is it related to something which needs upgrading. Here is my composer file:

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.8.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "2.5.*",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.6.*",
        "twig/extensions": "1.3.*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.8",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~5.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "snc/redis-bundle": "dev-master",
        "predis/predis": "1.0.*",
        "symfony/class-loader": "v2.8.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "~3.0",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "~2.7"
    },
```

I just wish the debug was slightly more helpful in regards to what it was doing it at the time. Or what file/line the error occurred at.

Comment: How did you fix your issue?! I have the same issue atm...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of a work around than a fix.

Basically in the version change they added code which wants to modify repository files. Since these are auto generated, most of the time it is fine. If you have added code to any of them, which you are meant to do, especially if you are modifying the code as a user other than www-data, it breaks things.

So now, when I come to do getters and setters part of a databsse structure update, I run this:

```
sudo find ./src/MyBunddle/SiteBundle/Entity -name '*.php' ! -name '*Repository.php' -exec chown www-data \{\} \; -print
```

Not idea, but gets the job done.

If you need to changes things back for any reason, you can do it with

```
sudo find ./src/MyBundle/SiteBundle/Entity -name '*.php' ! -name '*Repository.php' -exec chown youUser \{\} \; -print
```

You can see them discussing the issue here:

https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/commit/caf30b889bb898620d843d1ec4940d01fa1d8877

Answer (score 0):

Check the `cache` folder ownership as well. If its same user, it shouldn't be a concern. Still do a double check.

Additionally, if this doesn't work, please disable `safe_mode` for time being and check once again.

Comment: I have worked out the issue. The cache folder is not at fault. Neither is the log folder. Both are things I checked though as likely issues.