# doctrine:generate:entities chmod operation not permitted

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony

I wanted to continu a project I haven't touched in a while, and came across this error when executing
`php bin/console doctrine:generate:entites SalonBundle` (it's from shell, so it use PHP CLI)

```
Generating entities for bundle "SalonBundle"
> backing up Salon.php to Salon.php~
> generating SalonBundle\Entity\Salon

[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]
Warning: chmod(): Operation not permitted

doctrine:generate:entities [--path PATH] [--no-backup] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--] <command> <name>
```

To begin with, I'm not sure why Symfony try a `chmod`
All files are owned by `root:www-data`
File permissions are `rw-rw-r--`
My user is in group `www-data`
upload, creating file, copy, move, etc works fine

The permissions are set via a script which run the following commands
`$targetDir`is the path passed as argument to the script.

```
chown -R root:www-data $targerDir
find $targerDir -type d -exec chmod ug+rwx "{}" \;
find $targerDir -type f -exec chmod ug+rw "{}" \;
find $targerDir -type d -exec chmod g+s "{}" \;
find $targerDir -type d -exec setfacl -m g:www-data:rwx,d:g:www-data:rwx "{}" \;
find $targerDir -type f -exec setfacl -m g:www-data:rw- "{}" \;
```

Just added -vvv to the command line as suggested by someone and got this:

```
Exception trace:
() at /var/www/3DH/salon/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/EntityGenerator.php:392
Symfony\Component\Debug\ErrorHandler->handleError() at n/a:n/a
chmod() at /var/www/3DH/salon/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/EntityGenerator.php:392
Doctrine\ORM\Tools\EntityGenerator->writeEntityClass() at /var/www/3DH/salon/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/EntityGenerator.php:347
Doctrine\ORM\Tools\EntityGenerator->generate() at /var/www/3DH/salon/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/Command/GenerateEntitiesDoctrineCommand.php:133
Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Command\GenerateEntitiesDoctrineCommand->execute() at /var/www/3DH/salon/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:256
Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /var/www/3DH/salon/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:837
Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /var/www/3DH/salon/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:187
Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /var/www/3DH/salon/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php:80
Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun() at /var/www/3DH/salon/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:118
Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /var/www/3DH/salon/bin/console:27
```

[This topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38772080/symfony2-doctrinegenerateentities-chmod-operation-not-permitted) provide no solutions
[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31200488/vagrant-symfony-chmod-permit) doesn't apply to me as I don't use vagrant (not installed)

Comment: why should the files be owned by root?

Comment: Doesn't matter who is file owner, as it's group who edit files. I never had that issue before. Not sure how it came to be. I'm not even sure why symfony try a `chmod`to begin with

Comment: hmn doublecheck subfolder/ Entity

Comment: Checked "just in case", but all file have `-rw-rw-r--+ 1 root www-data`. Nothing wrong here

Comment: well then i can only imagine the user that runs the webserver is not in that group, if you run apache check httpd.conf for user and group property

Comment: The php-cli may be use fast-cgi ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I understood the problem.
I would say I'm stupid in the first place I guess...

@john Smith: You weren't far off...

In fact, my problem is just logic...
Trying to chmod a file owned by root with a regular user is impossible...
And that's normal

Every files generated in the `src/` folder are made from the files(lets call them tools) in `/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/`
And of course files are owned by the user who user these tools (twig, entity, form, etc)
When generating a file, these tools try to chmod the new file in case we were dumb enough to not set right our folders & files permissions.

In my case, as I did a pass of my webperms script, all files were owner by `root:www-data`.
So of course, when I try to generate entities, it would fail because I wasn't the file owner anymore.

There are currently two solutions to this problem:

1. Change `src/` files ownership to user:www-data
2. Comment the `chmod`command in the tools located in `/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/`

I'm not sure how to contact the symfony team, but I would suggest to add an `if` condition, which would depend of a symfony parameter and allow us to bypass this `chmod`